# xcode - product - archive -distrubute app show error: archive contains nothing that can't be signed

Tags: ios, ionic5

my ionic project

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

build success!
and then go to xcode archive build success ;
already choose my team
and include arm64 structure;
when valid or distrbute app ,
it shows `The archive contains nothing that can be signed.`